# How is package.appxfragment file generated

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-winrt

I have an existing project and I am trying to create similar setup for new functionality. But there are errors and I see that the different between two is that there is no package.appxfragment file present in my lib project. I am wondering how this file get generated? Do I have to add manually or is it generated automatically?

Comment: What is a *"lib project"*?

Comment: by lib I mean static library

Comment: Maybe this should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-create-a-package-manifest-manually